# Google Play games are not authorized when installed from outside of Google Play

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-play

I have the following problem: when downloading my application from Google Play when entering the game, authorization in "Google Play games" occurs without errors, but if you install the game from some third-party source, then for some reason the authorization does not work.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Nothing, only work with Play store

Comment: That is, this is how it should work?

Comment: Yes only works in that way